# How to make jquery tooltip code?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

How to add tooltip in jquery?
I want to display title, but whatever I try does not work.

JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/5fsCK/](http://jsfiddle.net/5fsCK/)

example: http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/form.html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // What to put here?
});
```

Comment: you can use qtip2 http://qtip2.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really a need for jQuery UI or any other external resource. Just add a div with class 'tooltip' and initially set it to display: none. See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NJF8a/

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").on("focus", function () {
        $(".tooltip").hide();
        var left = $(this).width();
        var top = $(this).offset().top;
        $(".tooltip").css({
            position: "absolute",
            left: left,
            top: top
        }).html($(this).attr("title")).fadeIn(500);
    }).on("blur", function () {
        if ($(".tooltip").is(":visible")) $(".tooltip").fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: That approach kind of defeats the whole reusability aspect of jQuery + UI coding, but hey, whatever the customer wants :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add tooltip jquery file.
Add tooptip Js reference(`http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js`) to your header I have added. Please check [Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5fsCK/1). You can also use [Poshytip](http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/)

Answer (score 0):

Your example JSFiddle and the JQueryUI sample page work fine when combined:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5fsCK/1/

The only thing I did was include JQueryUI (and the sample code)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myform :input").tooltip({
        // place tooltip on the right edge
        position: "center right",
        // a little tweaking of the position
        offset: [-2, 30],
        // use the built-in fadeIn/fadeOut effect
        effect: "fade",
        // custom opacity setting
        opacity: 0.7
    });
});
```

*The position is not correct (styling issue), but I am dashing out the door right now* :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this working [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rkumar670/5fsCK/2/)

I added some External resources.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#demo-basic').poshytip({className: 'tip-darkgray',
            bgImageFrameSize: 11,
            offsetX: -25
});
$('#inputtext').poshytip({className: 'tip-darkgray',
            bgImageFrameSize: 11,
            offsetX: -25
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple code for adding tool tip:

```
$("element").attr('title', 'tool tip text');
```